# Unable to return queried API data in ASP.NET from repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, task

I am trying to return JSON data from an API. 
The API endpoint is "/api/getUserSchedule(int id)". 
It should return back JSON data where it has been filtered according to the staffId value, which is a foreign key to the taskSchedule table.

I can return all the data, as shown here using a different API endpoint [image: all API data]

However, I need it to return data based on staffID. 
I have created an interface which is implemented by a repository.

interface code

```
public interface ITaskScheduleRepository
{    
  Task<TaskSchedule> GetUserSchedule(int id);  
}
```

Repository code

```
        public async Task<TaskSchedule> GetUserSchedule(int id)
    {
        var userTaskSchedule = await _context.TaskSchedules
        .Where(s => s.staffId == id)
        .ToListAsync();                                    

         return userTaskSchedule; // error is here            
    }
```

controller code

```
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserTaskSchedule(int id)
    {
        var taskUserSchedule = await _repo.GetUserSchedule(id);

        if(taskUserSchedule != null)
            return Ok(taskUserSchedule);            

        return BadRequest("There are no tasks for this user");     
    }
```

error message

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to 'Schedular.API.Models.TaskSchedule' [Schedular.API]csharp(CS0029)

Comment: `var userTaskSchedule = await _context.TaskSchedules.SingleAsync(s => s.staffId == id);` ← You want 1, not a list of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return a `List<TaskSchedule>` (note your .ToListAsync()) call in your repository method) but your interface is defined to return a single `TaskSchedule`.  Update your interface and repository methods to return a `List<TaskSchedule>`

`Task<IList<TaskSchedule>> GetUserSchedule(int id);`

and

`public async Task<IList<TaskSchedule>> GetUserSchedule(int id)`

However, if a staff can only have one schedule, change your repository query to return a single item instead of a list of items.

```
var userTaskSchedule = await _context.TaskSchedules
    .Where(s => s.staffId == id)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();                                    

     return userTaskSchedule; /
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's resolved my problem.
But why do i not need to update the controller from Task<IActionResult> to Task<list<IActionresult>>

Comment: FWIW, I agree with @igor below.  A better name for your function here could be something like `Task<IList<TaskSchedule>> GetTaskSchedulesByStaffId(int staffId)`.  It makes maintaining / remembering what methods do much easier in the long run!

Comment: Oh, and to answer your follow on question, it's because your aren't returning a list of `IActionResults`, just one.  Your `IActionResult` is a single JSON response string that was created from a list of Task Schedules :)

Answer (score 1):

You want 1 `TaskSchedule` instance, not a list of them which is what `ToListAsync` will return.

Change

```
public async Task<TaskSchedule> GetUserSchedule(int id)
{
    var userTaskSchedule = await _context.TaskSchedules
        .Where(s => s.staffId == id)
        .ToListAsync();                                    

    return userTaskSchedule;
}
```

To this

```
public Task<TaskSchedule> GetUserSchedule(int id)
{
    return _context.TaskSchedules.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.staffId == id);
}
```

Note that I removed `async/await` because it is not necessary here. You can return the `Task<T>` instance directly to be awaited by the caller. If you need to do something with the returned instance before it is returned in this method then you can add back `async/await` and modify the instance before it is returned.

It is also considered good practice to add the word `Async` to the name of your methods as a suffix *if* a Task/Task is being returned. Example: `GetUserScheduleAsync` instead of `GetUserSchedule`.

---

Also you could also use `FirstAsync`, `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, or `SingleAsync` instead of `SingleAsync`. Which one depends on what your requirements are in the code.

Comment: Thanks, Igor, the return may be a list as my return type of staff can have multiple tasks. Tommy's answer has resolved my issue but it's interesting to know how to do it for a single task return.

Comment: @GolfBravo then I would strongly suggest you change your method name and variable names so they are not singular but plural.